# React conditionally cancel onBlur event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onblur

I need to conditionally cancel blur event on table cell. Sample react code;

```
onBlur = (event) => {
  if(someCondition) {
    //Cancel blur event. Prevent changing focus. 
  }
} 
render() {
    <table>
      <tr><td onBlur={this.onBlur}></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
}
```

I've looked `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();` methods, but not worked.
Please help me to achive preventing to change focus conditionally.

Comment: Are you saying you want to prevent the blur event action in some of the cell when some condition is satisfied? I am assuming the event is for all the cell.

Comment: @AaminKhan Yes you are right. There will be multiple cells. And I will coordinate changing focus between cells by some conditions.

Comment: I don't think you can use blur on td, blur usually works in input elements